# Display error message in span when radio btns group is not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display error message in span if the radio group buttons is not selected after submit, The problem is only the first occurrence of error_radio displays the error message, Any idea?

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1">
<input type="radio" name="radio1">
<span id="error_radio"></span>

<input type="radio" name="radio2">
<input type="radio" name="radio2">
<span id="error_radio"></span>

<input type="radio" name="radio3">
<input type="radio" name="radio3">
<span id="error_radio"></span>
```

This is my script

```
var names = [];
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
          names[$(this).attr('name')] = true; 
          });    

        for(radio in names)
        {
          var radio_buttons = $("input[name='" + radio + "']");
          var eNo = $("#err[]")
          if( radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 0)
          {
           error_radio.innerHTML= "No answer";
          } 
        }

       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/j2rc9/)

**HTML**

```
    <input type="radio" name="radio1">
<input type="radio" name="radio1">
<span id="error_radio"></span>
    <br/>

<input type="radio" name="radio2">
<input type="radio" name="radio2">
<span id="error_radio"></span>
    <br/>

<input type="radio" name="radio3">
<input type="radio" name="radio3">
<span id="error_radio"></span>
    </br>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="return check();"/>
```

**Jquery**

```
      function check(){
var names = [];
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
          names[$(this).attr('name')] = true; 
          });    

        for(radio in names)
        {
          var radio_buttons = $("input[name='" + radio + "']");

          if( radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 0)
          {
           radio_buttons.next('span').text("No answer");
          } 
            else
            {
                radio_buttons.next('span').text("");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working find on your fiddle, but when I tried to apply it on my own, it doesn't work. I think it is having problem with  this code radio_buttons.next('span').text("No answer"), is there other way for this?

Comment: @user2901740 Just paste your html

Comment: can you please check this one, I still can't make it work based on you  example http://jsfiddle.net/j2rc9/2/

Comment: @user2901740 Let me check

Comment: @user2901740 check my updated fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/j2rc9/3/

Comment: Hi I tested the codes but it seems the return false is the only one working not the part where in we display the error message.

Comment: @user2901740 sorry i can't unserstand

Comment: I found the solution, the problem is that, my radio button and span are separated by a textbox, that's why the .next() is not executing, and the .text() also had a problem so I changed it to .html instead. It is now working.. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you have reused your `id`s. Replace those with `class`. You can use `$(radio_buttons).nextUntil` to get the reference of the span on which to display the error message.

Comment: hmm.. can u provide example?

Answer (score 0):

you can only assign an ID onces
- `$("error_radio")` will always return the first element having that ID

-> they should have unique ID's.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle by below method
    `error_radio` make it **class** due to **id** should be  unique

**IN HTML**

```
<div class="rc">
<input type="radio" name="radio1">
<input type="radio" name="radio1">
<span class="error_radio"></span>
</div>

<div class="rc">
<input type="radio" name="radio2">
<input type="radio" name="radio2">
<span class="error_radio"></span>
</div>

<div class="rc">
<input type="radio" name="radio3">
<input type="radio" name="radio3">
<span class="error_radio"></span>
</div>
```

**In JS**

```
var names = [];
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
          names[$(this).attr('name')] = true; 
          });    

        for(radio in names)
        {
          var radio_buttons = $("input[name='" + radio + "']");
          var eNo = radio_button.closest(".rc").find(".error_radio");
          if( radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 0)
          {
           eNo.html("No answer");
          } 
        }

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

> HTML
>
> ```
> <input type="radio" name="radio1" checked>
> <input type="radio" name="radio1">
> <input type="radio" name="radio2">
> <input type="radio" name="radio2">
> <input type="radio" name="radio3">
> <input type="radio" name="radio3">
> <span id="error_radio"></span>
> ```
>
> Jquery
>
> ```
> if($('input[type="radio"]').attr("checked")=="checked")
> {
>  $("#error_radio").html("You are  checked");
> }
> else
> {
> $("#error_radio").html("You are not  checked");
> }
> ```
>
> [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R3peF/)

Comment: This only validates once, I have 3 span so I can identify which radio groups has is not checked

Comment: at that time , use 
if(!$('input[name="radio1"]').attr("checked")==checked)
//code to radio1
else if(!$('input[name="radio2"]').attr("checked")==checked)
//code goes on

Answer (score 0):

elements should have unique Ids.
so use class instead of ID elements.

since class element can be common and but ID cannot.

make it class due to id should be unique

Answer (score 0):

> THis is what exactly u want i think

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

var total = [],count=0;
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){
   // if($(this).attr("checked"))
    //{
          total.push($(this).attr("name"));
          count++;
  //}
})


if(count>0){

      $("#error_radio").html("You are  checked "+count+" radios  "+    total.join());
}
else
{
$("#error_radio").html("You are not  checked");
}
```

});

```
var total = [],count=0;
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){
   // if($(this).attr("checked"))
    //{
          total.push($(this).attr("name"));
          count++;
  //}})



if(count>0){

      $("#error_radio").html("You are  checked "+count+" radios  "+    total.join());
}
else
{
$("#error_radio").html("You are not  checked");
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3peF/2/)